# Giving a score to a randomly generated word

Tags: python

I am trying to give a score to a randomly generated word based on how close it is "myname" (I only generated a word with three letters to make sure it works first). Since I have only generating words with three letters, if the random word is "myn" then the score is 3.. if the random word is "mym" the score is 2, if the random word is "mim" the score is one.. etc etc. Essentially the "closeness" of the random word is based on whether the random word generated is in the first three letters of "myname" Here is the code I have thus far.

```
def generate(x):
    word = "myname"
    alpha_1 = alpha[random.randint(0,21)]
    vowel_1 = vowels[random.randint(0,4)]
    alpha_2 = alpha[random.randint(0,21)]
    two = {}
    for x in range(1,7315):
        two.update({alpha_1 + vowel_1 + alpha_2:0})  
        return two

generate(x)
```

Comment: That's great! ... Did you also have a question?

Comment: well, I am trying to give the randomly generated word a score (the score is based to how close the randomly generated word is to "myname" @RadLexus

Comment: Please define 'close'.

Comment: Hey @mathguy84 - typically, the questions have specific issues, with clear indications of what qualifies as success and failure. What type of scoring are you looking for? is `MYNAME` close? is `mynamf`? is it closer than `mynama` ? As such, your "question" is hard to help because we don't know what you're looking for.

Comment: Since I have only generating words with three letters, if the random word is "myn" then the score is 3.. if the random word is "mym" the score is 2, if the random word is "mim" the score is one.. etc etc. Essentially the "closeness" of the random word is based on whether the random word generated is in the first three letters of "myname" @LutzHorn

Comment: Absolutely shameless plug, but here's my attempt at trying to get a good "is this an English word?" score for a jumble of letters - [wordModel](https://github.com/anderson-dan-w/headlinepuzz/blob/master/wordModel.py). It's not perfect, probably not even very good, but hopefully this gives an idea of the underlying complexity of such a simple question.

Comment: @mathguy84 Add that whole comment to the question, it will make things clearer. Also, have you tried to implement any of that? If so, what went wrong? if not, which part is confusing you? It seems like you've got all you need for the solution, so maybe you're looking for help in how to structure it, etc.

Comment: Thus far, I am only generating the first three letters of the word. So "myn" is exact in the three letter case "mym" is close and off by one (so score should be 2) "nok" is completely off so score should be 0.. does that make sense @dwanderson

Comment: yeah I have no idea how to structure it.. I can't seem to come up with a way to score it @dwanderson

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [fuzzy matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_matching_(computer-assisted_translation)). Try using fuzzywuzzy (`pip install fuzzywuzzy`). You can use the doc [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy) to know how it works,but, basically :

- Import the module `from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process`
- Then, the ratio of the two strings : `fuzz.ratio(myname, "The name to compare with")`

You can also see if the name is contained in the string using partial ratio :
`fuzz.partial_ratio("abcdef", "bcd")`  will return 100 (%) as bcd is in a**bcd**ef
`fuzz.partial_ratio("aaaa", "abcd")` will return 25 (%) as the string is not really contained in the other one : only 1 letter is common.